# Why is the result in the below code 1? when exactly does rounding happen?

Tags: r

Could someone please explain why the result in the below code is 1?

```
> a <- 2^(-52)
> c <- 1
> a+c
```

If, in the above code, "a" gets rounded to 0 or something while adding, then why does the below code does not return a zero?

```
> a <- 2^(-52)
> b <- 2^(-53)
> a+b
```

Comment: by the way, is this a class/homework question? It's not disallowed, but I like to know.

Comment: No, this is not a class/homework question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read up on floating point arithmetic: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) doesn't cover your exact question, but gives useful references (more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)).  The difference between the two examples is that in the first case the addends are on very different scales, while in the second case they are of similar magnitudes. `?.Machine` will give you some of the relevant values, especially `.Machine$double.eps` (which is the *smallest number such that* `1+x > x`) (although it won't explain floating point arithmetic for you).

(@BrianMontgomery's answer points out that technically this is only true if you use `a <- 2^(-53)` (or smaller).)

(I don't think this answer is great, but it will do until someone wants to come along and explain the floating point issues underlying this example in more detail.)

Answer (score 0):

It's not really 1, R just doesn't display it by default.
Also, don't use c as variable in R, as c() is the combine function.

```
a <- 2^(-52)
d <- 1
e <- a + d
e # shows 1
e - 1 # gives [1] 2.220446e-16
```

Comment: fair enough, but if they had used `2^(-53)` in their example they'd get catastrophic loss of precision: `(1+2^(-53))-1` is exactly zero.